# chartjs - no smooth rendering on time series plot

Tags: time, chart.js, rendering, series, smoothing

On basic chartjs line plot
https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/basic.html
the chart animates (i.e. renders smoothly) when the "Randomize Data" button is clicked.

But the time series plot here
https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/scales/time/financial.html
doesn't render smoothly when the "Update" button is clicked.

How can smooth rendering be achieved on the time series plot.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have smooth rendering, you need to define/increase the `animation.duration` option.

```
options: {
  animation: {
    duration: 2000
  },
  ...
```

> [`duration`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/animations.html#animation-configuration): The number of milliseconds an animation takes.

Comment: @Brij Mohan: Glad I could help. Please mark my answer as accepted if you think it was the solution to your question (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399/2358409)